# Gsuite python client - Insert members to a group

Tags: python, google-api-python-client, google-workspace

I'm trying to insert members into a group in Gsuite. But I am not succeeding. The script returns no error or adds member to the group.

That's my code and these are the parameters add_member_to_group(member='someone@domain.com', groupKey='my-alias@domain.com'):

PS: I can list all members of 'my-alias@domain.com'.

```py
    def add_member_to_group(self, member, groupKey):
        log.info('Adding member {} to group {}'.format(member, groupKey))
        if isinstance(member, dict):
            body = {
                'kind': "admin#directory#member",
                'role': member['role'],
                'type': member['type'],
                'email': member['email']
            }
        else:
            body = {
                'kind': "admin#directory#member",
                'role': 'MEMBER',  # OWNER, MANAGER, MEMBER
                'email': member
            }
        req = self.members.insert(body=body, groupKey=groupKey)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I forgot to execute the request:

```py
req = self.members.insert(body=body, groupKey=groupKey)
response = req.execute()
```